# How to use Asp.NET Custom WebControl in Source-View

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I created a Label control inheriting from Label WebControl in CustomLabel.vb in my project where I want to use it. And I would like to use the code below in source-view as such:

```
<custom:SettingLabel ID="lblHelloWorld" runat="server"/>
```

How can I do that **without** creating a `WebContolLibrary` and using it as reference?

```
Namespace InternetLending.Controls
    Public Class SettingLabel
        Inherits Label

        Protected msDefaultText As String
        Protected moConfigXML As New ConfigXMLParser()

        Public Overridable Property DefaultText() As String
            Get
                Return Me.msDefaultText
            End Get
            Set(ByVal vsValue As String)
                Me.msDefaultText = vsValue
            End Set
        End Property

        Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            MyBase.OnLoad(e)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.moConfigXML.GetLabelTextByID(Me.ID)) Then
                Me.Text = Me.moConfigXML.GetLabelTextByID(Me.ID)
            Else
                Me.Text = Me.DefaultText
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add this to the top of your page. You don't need to make a separate library or anything.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Assembly" Namespace="Assembly.Controls" TagPrefix="custom" %>
```

Comment: So you say, after adding that declaration, I can add `SettingLabel` as  Control in SourceView with declarative syntax?

Comment: Didn't work and this is the error: `Could not load file or assembly 'InternetLending.Controls.SettingLabel' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` This is my declarative:  `<%@ Register Assembly="InternetLending.Controls.SettingLabel" Namespace="InternetLending.Controls.SettingLabel" TagPrefix="custom" %>`

Comment: Assembly should just be the name of your project's assembly, and Namespace should be the namespace that your control is in. So in this case, I'm guessing your project is called "InternetLending", so you'd want it to be Assembly="InternetLending" Namespace="InternetLending.Controls".

Comment: Can you paste what you have now?

Comment: <%@ Register Assembly="InternetLending" Namespace="InternetLending.Controls" TagPrefix="custom" %>

Comment: Strange, that should work fine assuming the assembly/nameespace are correct. You should be able to then access the control via <custom:SettingLabel></custom:SettingLabel>

Comment: Could you post a sample code that you tested and works fine? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not taking into account the default namespace.

Try using the following directive:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="InternetLending" Namespace="InternetLending.InternetLending.Controls" TagPrefix="custom" %>
```

Or change your Namespace for the `SettingLabel` control like so:

```
Namespace Controls
    Public Class SettingLabel
        Inherits Label
```

and then use the following directive:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="InternetLending" Namespace="InternetLending.Controls" TagPrefix="custom" %>
```

See: [Managing Namespaces in VB.Net](http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/net/nettip40.asp) for more info.

Comment: I've tried these ones too before and won't work. The error message is same as with the ones commented under rossisdead answer.

Comment: Are you sure, because based on your code sample the namespace for your `Settinglabel` control is: `InternetLending.InternetLending.Controls`. Which would mean the register directive would be as follows: `<%@ Register Assembly="InternetLending" Namespace="InternetLending.InternetLending.Controls" TagPrefix="custom" %>`.

Comment: Of course, the above is dependent on your assembly name and root namespace being `InternetLending`. You can check this via the Application tab of your projects properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just register the assembly in the web.config or page directive, even if it's in the same project.

```
<add tagPrefix="MyControls" namespace="MyProgram.Controls.MyControl" assembly="MyProgram.Controls.MyControl" tagName="MyControl" />
```

Comment: Didn't work, the error message is: `Parser Error Message: The directive is missing a 'src' attribute.`

Comment: Try removing the `tagName` attribute.